# On hover of select options menu loses focus

Tags: html, menu, internet-explorer-8

I have a menu and one of the items in the menu is a `select` element. Only in IE 8, when I hover on the select `options` the menu loses focus and closes. It works fine in Firefox. Any help would be appreciated

You can refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2Et9r/1/) fiddle for the code.

**Note** : I am open to solutions using `js` and `jquery`

**EDIT** : I do not want an alternate to the select.

Comment: I fooled around with it in IE9 (don't have 8 available) using jQuery.  It's not perfect but it does partially have the effect you're trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/vUger/1/

Comment: @Stieffers : Now the menu remains in an open state after the select loses focus.

Comment: I would just go with Sable Fost's solution.  There doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to manage a solution in IE using jQuery.

Comment: Sables option works because the height of the `ul` is growing with the larger list.  With the `select`, the height of the `ul` doesn't grow with the number of `options`.  If you could figure out how to grow that height with the number of options...

Comment: @Stieffers : The problem is I am not allowed to change the select.

Comment: @Cypher : I attempted to add height to the UL using jQuery, which worked, but IE seems to see the select object as independent of the UL, so the solution did not work. See http://jsfiddle.net/znxYq/

Comment: How is it given to you?  Can you convert the list by parsing the select?

Comment: @SableFoste : I should be able to parse the select

Answer (score -1):

Drop the SELECT option.  Try replacing it with a sub list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <body>
    <ul> Numbers
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>        
        <li>
            Select  -->
            <ul>
                <li>
                    One
                </li>
                <li>
                    Two
                </li>
                <li>
                    Three
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This works in both Chrome and IE.